# AWS Lambda function to populate DynamoDB table using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a DynamoDB table called "GoodTable", I am trying to fill the table with attributes like ("region","ebs_volume_size","instance_type",etc) which can be found from "templat_json" in a dict format. I have a lambda code that works in the console not sure how to convert it using boto:
This is my lambda function code :

```
import boto3
import time
import json
import meta_templates
from jinja2 import Template
from template_utils import create_aws_iam_policy_template 
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
lambd = boto3.client('lambda')

response = lambd.create_function(
    FunctionName='TrailLogs',
    Runtime='nodejs'|'nodejs4.3'|'nodejs6.10'|'nodejs8.10'|'java8'|'python2.7'|'python3.6'|'dotnetcore1.0'|'dotnetcore2.0'|'dotnetcore2.1'|'nodejs4.3-edge'|'go1.x',
    Role='string',
    Handler='string',
    Code={
        'ZipFile': b'bytes',
        'S3Bucket': 'string',
        'S3Key': 'string',
        'S3ObjectVersion': 'string',
        'ImageUri': 'string'
    },
)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  template_json = create_aws_iam_policy_template(**event)

  table = dynamodb.Table('GoodTable')
  response = table.put_item(
      Item= {
          'Content': 'Volume Size', 
          'Details': template_json.get('ebs_volume_size'),
      }
  )
  response = table.put_item(
      Item= {
          'Content': 'Instance Type', 
          'Details': template_json.get('instance_type'),
      }
  )
  response = table.put_item(
      Item= {
          'Content': 'Region', 
          'Details': template_json.get('region'),
      }
  )
```

Comment: What is the posted code supposed to be? Why does it include the copy/pasted [create_function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_function) request syntax from the boto3 documentation?

Comment: I am not sure what to fill int hose things, how do I give DyanmoDB permissions to my lambda function using boto

Comment: You generally don't use boto3 to create, deploy and enable Lambda functions. You can, but you typically don't. Instead you typically use something like AWS SAM or the serverless framework. You then trigger your Lambda function from some kind of event or API, or directly via the Lambda SDK's InvokeFunction call.

Comment: I have worked it out using a console but I need to do it using Boto, I think SAM also could be a good idea is there a good place to start because AWS documentation is too basic for this kind of use case

Comment: I have the values coming in from another function which is a module so I don't know how to convert that into SAM as well